# How do I obtain an odds ratio from logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, odds-ratio

```
LR1<-LRtest1$LR1
 > LR2<-LRtest1$LR2


> plot(LR2, jitter(LR1, 0.15), pch = 19,
+ xlab = "Count", ylab = "LR1 (0 - Trach, 1 - Ntrach)")
> model <-glm(LR1~LR2, binomial)
```

Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

```
> summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = LR1 ~ LR2, family = binomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6579  -0.5952  -0.2976   0.2987   1.9068  

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.6409     0.4734  -3.466 0.000528 ***
LR2           0.4539     0.1497   3.032 0.002429 **
```

---

```
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 83.178  on 59  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 46.705  on 58  degrees of freedom
AIC: 50.705

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 9

> xv <- seq(min(LR2), max(LR2),0.01)
> yv <- predict(model, list(LR2= xv), type = "response")
> lines(xv,yv,col= "red")
> summary(LRtest1)
  LR1           LR2
```

Min.   :0.0   Min.   :  0.00
1st Qu.:0.0   1st Qu.:  0.00
Median :0.5   Median :  2.00
Mean   :0.5   Mean   : 14.77
3rd Qu.:1.0   3rd Qu.:  9.50
Max.   :1.0   Max.   :156.00

[image: This is my code for logistic regression] I am looking for a way to do the odds ratio. I tried EpiR and exec and both do not work. I also tried fisher's test it shows me the p-value only and does not even show the odds ratio.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read. Plesse format it properly. Also try `exp(coef(mymodel))`

Comment: It does not work >exp(coef(odds1))
Error in exp(coef(odds1)) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `coefficients`.

Comment: But you didnt fix the formatting so it is almost impossible to help you. Also try  `exp(0.4539)`

Comment: Sorry. a bit new. Hopefully the picture clarifies it. If I do that it gives me one number, is this the odds ratio? It does not have a title so I am not sure:  exp(0.4539)
[1] 1.574441---- Also you do it this way exp(estimate #) so you will be using the estimate#?

Comment: Please don't post a pictiure of your code and output - it is then impossible to copy parts from it !! Just copy the text and put ``` above and below it. Or if it's just a few lines, put 4 spaces in front of each line.  The system will format it properly.  The odds ratio for a categorical variable is just the exponentiated coefficient.

Answer (score 4):

The odds ratio for `LR2` is simply the exponentiated value of the estimate for it:

```
> exp(0.4539)
[1] 1.574441
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not please let us know why so that it can be improved